# How do I make this image 100% fill the container?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have the code below. My problem is that if I add too much text, it pushes down the entire row and the image has extra space underneath. How can I make sure that the image always fills out its container and its height adapts to the amount of content in the other column?

Here is an image in case the code snippet does not show exactly what I see.

[image]

I am using Bootstrap4.

```css
.lesson-heading h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.lesson {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
.lesson-img {
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    position: relative;
}
.trial-badge {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: green;
    top: 10px;
    left: 25px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 3px 10px;
}
.lesson-content-header {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
.lesson-content {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.lesson-title h4 a {
    font-size: 22px; 
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #333131;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.lesson-title h4 a:hover {
    color: #ed6310;
    transition: .7s;
}
.lesson-status-completed i {
    color: green;
}
.lesson-status-locked i, .lesson-status-new i {
    color: #ccc;
}
.lesson-desc p {
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0-2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="lesson">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="lesson-img">
                    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/04/07/23/11/content-marketing-4111003__340.jpg" alt=""
                        class="img-fluid">
                </div>
                <div class="trial-badge">
                    <span>Trial</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8 lesson-content">
                <div class="lesson-content-header d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <div class="lesson-title">
                        <h4><a href="#">This is the title of the lesson</a></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="lesson-status-completed"><i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i></div>
                </div>
                <div class="lesson-desc">
                    <p>This is the description of the lesson. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Ullam aliquid nam adipisci in quae voluptate sunt fuga impedit. Ullam aliquid nam adipisci in
                        quae voluptate sunt fuga impedit. Ullam aliquid nam adipisci in quae voluptate sunt fuga
                        impedit.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're going to struggle with this as the image proportions won't work as you increase the text length. Its a landscape image which means that if you were going to stretch the height of it, the width would be cut off. Usual way around this is to set image as background image and then use background-size: cover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try this code:**

```css
.lesson-heading h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.lesson {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
.lesson-img {
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    position: relative;
}
.trial-badge {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: green;
    top: 10px;
    left: 25px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 3px 10px;
}
.lesson-content-header {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
.lesson-content {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.lesson-title h4 a {
    font-size: 22px; 
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #333131;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.lesson-title h4 a:hover {
    color: #ed6310;
    transition: .7s;
}
.lesson-status-completed i {
    color: green;
}
.lesson-status-locked i, .lesson-status-new i {
    color: #ccc;
}
.lesson-desc p {
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0-2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="lesson">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="lesson-img h-100">
                    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/04/07/23/11/content-marketing-4111003__340.jpg" alt=""
                        class="img-fluid h-100">
                </div>
                <div class="trial-badge">
                    <span>Trial</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8 lesson-content">
                <div class="lesson-content-header d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <div class="lesson-title">
                        <h4><a href="#">This is the title of the lesson</a></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="lesson-status-completed"><i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i></div>
                </div>
                <div class="lesson-desc">
                    <p>This is the description of the lesson. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Ullam aliquid nam adipisci in quae voluptate sunt fuga impedit. Ullam aliquid nam adipisci in
                        quae voluptate sunt fuga impedit. Ullam aliquid nam adipisci in quae voluptate sunt fuga
                        impedit.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Although this literally answers the question, its not going to be any good in a production environment as you're stretching the image.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right.To solve this problem, you can use `object-fit`